# Does the netstat counter wrap around? And over what period are they collected?

Tags: netstat, solaris-10

If I run netstat -s on my solaris 10 box, I got a lot of network statistics.

Are these counters since the time of system boot, or some other arbitrary period?

And some of the numbers are quite large. Does it wrap-around at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) System boot

2) no it depends on what the variable type is ( like long integer etc). You dont have a  direct way to make it in readable format unless you pipe the output to do some math. A quick example ( pls ignore the first line. Did not have the patience to get rid of it)

[root@host]# netstat -i

Kernel Interface table

Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg

ens3      1500     1457      0      0 0          1050      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536        6      0      0 0             6      0      0      0 LRU

[root@host]# netstat -i | awk '{print $1, $2/1024}'

Kernel 0

Iface 0

ens3 1.46484

lo 64

I hope this helps.